# Getting information from an online database with iOS

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to query the ncbi public database.  When I look at the network stream, all I can see is that the response header is text/html.  Does that mean I have to parse the text/html in iOS to get the information I want in a database?  Thanks.

Comment: how exactly are you querying the NCBI database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting data in the form of a HTML document, you will indeed have to parse the HTML to extract the data.